# FIFO Queue Head Pointer incorrect

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, queue, fifo

I need to implement a queue in C for a small part of a homework project.  I've been doing this for a few years in various languages so I'm surprised that I'm having so much trouble.  My issue is that the value of Head is continuously being changed to the most recent value added.

Here is my code so far:

```
void Enqueue( fifo* queue, int customerData)
{
//Determine if a head or tail exists
int tailExists = 0;

if(queue->tail->customerId >= 0){
    tailExists = 1;
}

//Create new elements

struct fifo_element a, *element;
element = &a;

if(tailExists == 1)
    printf("test2 the head is %d\t", queue->head->customerId);

element->customerId = customerData;

if(tailExists == 1)
    printf("test3 the head is %d\t", queue->head->customerId);

//Set the next element to the current tail
if(tailExists == 1)
    element->next = queue->tail;
else
    element->next = NULL;

//Set the prev element to null
element->prev = NULL;

//Set the last element's previous to the new element
if(tailExists == 1){
    queue->tail->prev = element;
}

//Set the tail to the new element
queue->tail = element;
if(tailExists == 0){
    queue->head = element;
}

printf("the head is %d\t", queue->head->customerId);
printf("the tail is %d\t", queue->tail->customerId);

}
```

Based on the printf lines, the line `element->customerId = customerData;` is causing the Head value to change.  However, I don't see how this is possible...  Why is this happening?

(My test program just runs a for loop from 0->4, calling enqueue with a customerData value of i).

Comment: `element = &a;` You're inserting a pointer to a local variable in your queue, after the function returns, the local variable doesn't exist anymore, and the queue contains a dangling pointer. `malloc` the memory, `struct fifo_element *element = malloc(sizeof *element);`.

Comment: Do yourself a *huge* favor and don't try and use some sentinel node as the symbol of whether your queue is "empty" or not. Properly manage your tail and head pointers to be either pointing to valid content *in* the queue, or NULL if the queue is empty. The rest will practically write itself if you follow this strictly.

Answer (score 0):

```
element = &a;
```

You're inserting a pointer to a local variable in your queue, after the function returns, the local variable doesn't exist anymore, and the queue contains a dangling pointer.

`malloc()` the memory:

```
struct fifo_element *element = malloc(sizeof *element);
```

Comment: Just Making Daniel's comment into an answer so this doesn't show up under *unanswered* anymore.